# Transparent Popover and black parent UIViewController

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I want to show transparent ViewController over the parent VC.

```
let sdVC = ShowDetailsViewController()
sdVC.delegate = self
sdVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
self.presentViewController(sdVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It works ok in almost all the cases except one. My parent VC is in the TabBar, and this combination of actions is broken:

1. Tap on the button to show transparent VC. — works.
2. Tap on any other tab at the TabBar. — works.
3. Tap back to the tab with transparent VC — transparent VC is ok, but his parent VC is completely black.
4. Close transparent VC. Parent VC is still black.
5. Tap on any other tab at the TabBar and back — Parent VC is ok.

How do I avoid 3 and 4?

Comment: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598099/present-uiviewcontroller-as-a-modal-with-transparent-background/39262554#39262554

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how your answer there is helping me. My code works (I have transparent controller after all, and parent controller is ok unless I go to other tabs and back — in this case parent controller is black, and I want to fix this).

Comment: oh okay friend :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .overFullscreen not OverCurrentContext.
See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45991501/325267

Comment: It'd be better if you flagged the question as a duplicate instead